# how to remove toggle class to limit after 5 events selected in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have functionality which will add toggle class clicked event when click div tag add class `clicked` so that it will be active if they clicked 5 services I need to disable after that. how could I do that.

http://jsfiddle.net/t8d322k6/

This is my code

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6  home_s"> 
    <a class="get_category" id="36" href="javascript:void(0)">
        <img class="img-responsive img-center" src="#">
        <span>Architect</span>
    </a>
     <input type="hidden" value="" id="categories36" name="categories[]">
</div>
```

JS

```
$(".iconshome .home_s").click(function() { 
$(this).toggleClass('clicked');
        if($(this).hasClass('clicked')){
            alert($(".clicked").length);
            if($(".clicked").length>=5){
                alert("hi");
                $(this).unbind('click');
                    $(this).off('click');
                    return false;
            }else{
                return true;

            }
        }
})
```

Comment: What problems are you running into with your current solution/what else have you tried? Why not just `return false` in the click listener if `$(".click").length >= 5` rather than turning off the listener?

Comment: i would like to disable the click event after  5 services selected and showing alert message

Comment: Your code is not very clear. Please have javascript and html separate. Also, it would help if you included a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) with a small example of what you have now.

Comment: actually there will mutliple div like this i need to select only 5 events after this need to disable click event so again user need to unselect from the 5 and select other events but maximum will be 5

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get your problem fully, but from my understanding, please try the following code. There may have good solutions than this, give a try on this :

HTML:

```
<div class="home_s" data-counter="0">
   <a class="get_category" id="36" href="javascript:void(0)">
       <img class="img-responsive img-center" src="#">
       <span>Architect</span>
   </a>
   <input type="hidden" value="" id="categories36" name="categories[]">
</div>
```

JS:

```
 $(".home_s").click(function (event) {
    var count = parseInt($(this).attr("data-counter"));
    alert(count)
    if (count == 5) {
        $(this).off('click');
        } else {
             $(this).attr("data-counter", count + 1)
        }
  })
```

Comment: hi sabith , there will multiple div how to get the counter

Comment: You will get counter using event.target as $(event.target).attr("data-counter"). (event.target) will give you the current div on which you clicked.